# git submodule shallow downloads everything

Tags: git, tags, size, branch, git-submodules

I have recently migrated two directories of our svn repository to our locally hosted gitlab. One is a single application (let's call it app1), with linear history and "few" commits (under 100).

But the second one is "core", with very long history, lots of commits and about 10 tags.

While using svn, I have just downloaded the whole repository, where i had
/apps/app1/ and /apps/shared/core/, and I have just linked from my app to ../shared/core/tags/tag20160101.

Now, I want to use git to save time and space. I have migrated both "app1" and "core" succesfully to gitlab using svn2git. I deleted both local repositories that I have used to migrate, and cloned "app1", and executed

```
git submodule add ../core.git submodules/core --depth=1 -b tag20160101
```

Now the problem is, that while the submodules/core directory is about 300MB in size (just the size of 20160101 tag), the .git directory in main repository bumped out to 4GB. It just downloaded everything.

Did I do something wrong or is there a way to download only the useful tag to save space?

There may be a time when I am working on 5 different projects, each including "core" on different tag, and I do not want to download 4GB of not needed files for each project.

Comment: The `--depth` option to `git submodule add` was new in Git version 1.8.4 (which is pretty old, but there are even older versions of Git in use today). What version of Git do you have? I would imagine it must be newer since you said the main `.git` directory ballooned, and submodule absorption was new in 2.something.

Comment: git version 2.13.0, so do I need to study absorbgitdirs, right? At first glance I don't see how it should help me, but I will continue.

Comment: Well, the point here was: 2.13 should obey `--depth`. It's not clear what is going wrong.